# Best practice concerning storage of PHP supported timezones in a mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, timezone

I am wondering what the best practice is for storage of PHP's ['supported timezones'](http://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.php) is.  I am storing each user's timezone so I can do conversions to/from UTC to their local time.  Would you store it as a string in a varchar type field?  In this case what is the longest possible supported timezone string?  Is there a better practice for storing these?  Simply storing timezone offset is not an option as it does not take into account DST automatically like PHP's datetime object does.

Comment: Why overcomplicate things? Store the name as a `VARCHAR(255)` and call it a day. Takes up no more space than necessary and if at some point you have a longer-than-255-characters timezone bug... that problem will be dealt with when it arises.

Comment: A good solution I guess I didn't fully understand how VARCHAR worked.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is *almost* an exact duplicate of this question:
 [Proper way to store a timezone in a database?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15824482/634824)

But I will address the few other points you mentioned:

- PHP time zones are [IANA time zones](http://www.iana.org/time-zones).
- Just store the name in a `varchar`. There is some discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3477894/634824) about field length of time zone names.  `varchar(32)` would work, but just to be on the safe side I would leave some extra room for future changes.  255 is probably overkill, but perhaps `varchar(50)` would be reasonable.
- A lot of folks recommend storing UTC in the database.  This is *sometimes* a good practice, but I don't like it when recommended as something you should *always* do.  There are good reasons to use UTC and there are good reasons to use local time.
- If you use UTC, you will need the time zone name and will have to convert to and from local time on input and output.
- If you use local time, you should always store the time zone *offset* in addition to the local time.  This is because of potentially ambiguous local times during DST transitions.  Some databases have a type just for this, such as `TIMESTAMP WITH TIMEZONE` in Oracle or Postgres or `DATETIMEOFFSET` in SQL Sever.  Unfortunately, MySql doesn't have a type for this, so you will need two columns.
- If your data is just recorded once and never changed (such as a recorded event time), then either of these options is viable.  UTC has the advantage of being ready for math and conversions.  Local time has the the advantage of preserving the perspective of the observer.  See [DateTime vs DateTimeOffset](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4331189/634824) which is about .Net, but the concepts still apply here.
- If you are going to be *editing* these times, then you're going to need the time zone name either way, so you might as well store it.  You can decide whether it makes sense to store it per recorded timestamp, or just once per user.  You should think about what you would want to happen if the user changes their time zone.  Should it apply everywhere? Or only to newly recorded entries?

There are some practical reasons I can think of to *not* store as UTC:

- If you are running a report that will output many hundreds or thousands of rows, and the desired output is in the local time as recorded, then having to convert from UTC many times repeatedly in a tight loop *may* slow down the execution time of the report.
- Sometimes there is a legal requirement that the time is stored precisely as it is presented.  A non-technical auditor might not allow for any type of conversions and would see UTC times as unlawful.  If they looked at a local-time-plus-offset value, they would *probably* not care about the offset portion, and would be satisfied with the local time value.   I know this seems silly, but there are industries and jurisdictions where these requirements do exist.
- Sometimes you don't want to actually refer to a single instant in time, but specifically to a localized representation of that time.  Say you have restaurants around the USA that all open at 6:00 AM.  Well, that 6:00 AM is a different moment in Pacific time than it is in Eastern time.  Storing these as UTC could lead to invalid assumptions, especially around DST changes.

In most other cases, I recommend storing as UTC.  But you will have to decide what works best for your particular requirements.

Answer (score 2):

store all times as UTC then 
create another field that has the timezone offset.

This is really not a PHP issue but a database best practices for using timezones.  Always save data in UTC.  Have another field for the TZ offset e.g. -10 or as a timezone e.g. 'Europe/Amsterdam'.  For me, I use pytz in python to deal with this stuff.

You will always be able to recover DST.

Comment: Storing UTC offset in the database is a poor solution because it does not take into account DST changes in different timezones.  However if you pass PHP's datetime object a 'supported timezone' it will automatically take into account DST when converting between timezones.

Comment: thats why I suggested timezone as well. Then you can recover. There are cases why one also stores offest in addition to timezone.

Answer (score 2):

I always store dates & times as unix timestamps in an integer field. That way I know exactly what I am gong to get from my database. I would recommend storing the timezone in a text field   using the string representations in [this list](http://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.php), which you already know about.

For example a table like this called stackoverflow, in a database also called stackoverflow:-

```
+--+----------+-------------+
|id|date_time |time_zone    |
+--+----------+-------------+
|1 |1373212914|Europe/London|
|2 |1373212914|Europe/Rome  |
+--+----------+-------------+
```

Then you would hydrate your DateTime objects something like this:-

```PHP
$dsn = 'mysql:dbname=stackoverflow;host=127.0.0.1';
$user = 'stackoverflow';
$password = 'stackoverflow';

try {
    $dbh = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
    $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
}

$sql = 'select date_time, time_zone from stackoverflow';
$statement = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$statement->execute();
$results = $statement->fetchAll();
foreach($results as $result){
    $datetimes[] = (new \DateTime())->setTimestamp((int)$result['date_time'])->setTimezone(new \DateTimeZone($result['time_zone']));
}

var_dump($datetimes);
```

Which gives this output:-

```
array (size=2)
  0 => 
    object(DateTime)[3]
      public 'date' => string '2013-07-07 17:01:54' (length=19)
      public 'timezone_type' => int 3
      public 'timezone' => string 'Europe/London' (length=13)
  1 => 
    object(DateTime)[4]
      public 'date' => string '2013-07-07 18:01:54' (length=19)
      public 'timezone_type' => int 3
      public 'timezone' => string 'Europe/Rome' (length=11)
```

Inspecting the table will show that both entries have the same timestamp, which equates to `2013-07-07 16:01:54 UTC`, but are represented correctly in the stored timezone when sent to the client.